# What does "##" in a shell script mean?

Tags: bash

While putting together a script, I came across this command:

```bash
f=${file##*/}
```

I am curious to know, what does `##` in this line mean?

Answer (score 24):

In `bash`, it removes a prefix pattern. Here, it's basically giving you everything after the last path separator `/`, by greedily removing the prefix `*/`, any number of characters followed by `/`):

```
pax> fspec=/path/to/some/file.txt ; echo ${fspec##*/}
file.txt
```

Greedy in this context means matches as much as possible. There's also a non-greedy variant (matches the smallest possible sequence), and equivalents for suffixes:

```
pax> echo ${fspec#*/}    # non-greedy prefix removal
path/to/some/file.txt
pax> echo ${fspec%%/*}   # greedy suffix removal (no output)
pax> echo ${fspec%/*}    # non-greedy suffix removal
/path/to/some
```

The `##*/` and `%/*` are roughly equivalent to what you get from `basename` and `dirname` respectively, but within `bash` so you don't have to invoke an external program:

```
pax> basename ${fspec} ; dirname ${fspec}
file.txt
/path/to/some
```

---

For what it's worth, the way I remember the different effects of `##`, `%%`, `#`, and `%`, is as follows. They are "removers" of various types.

Because `#` often comes *before* a number (as in `#1`), it removes stuff at the start. Similarly, `%` often comes *after* a number (`50%`) so it removes stuff at the end.

Then the only distinction is the greedy/non-greedy aspect. Having more of the character (`##` or `%%`) obviously means you're greedy, otherwise you'd share them :-)

Comment: And I believe the Korn shell had this notation before Bash did; it is also available in the Korn shell, at any rate.

Comment: Just be aware that `%%/*` isn't an exact replacement for dirname. If you feed dirname a bare file name it returns '.', while `%%/*` returns the name unchanged. (In a script that could lead to things like creating a directory with the file name instead of recognizing the current directory already exists.)

Comment: Is there a way to be greedy to a certain extent? For example let's say I have the following: `fspec=/path/to/some/file.txt ` and I want the following output: `some/file.txt`

Comment: @AMerii: off the top of my head, I would say no with those operators. But I'm sure that, if you asked a question, it would get a few decent answers on other approaches. For example: `echo '/path/to/some/file.txt' | perl -pne 's?.*/([^/]*/[^/]*$)?\1?'` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will be creating a new question then :D

Comment: This answer is bash-specific (fair, since the question is tagged that way), but note that these parameter expansion features are much more widely available (e.g. with `sh`), as they are part of the POSIX standard: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html